# Play2 Scala - Global cannot be cast to play.GlobalSettings

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I've tried to create a Global object in app/Global.scala to run an Akka scheduler, like some other SO post was saying.

My code is nearly a copy/paste of the Global object tutorial, but on startup I get the following error:

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
PlayException: Cannot init the Global object [Global cannot be cast to play.GlobalSettings]
    at play.api.PlayException$.apply(Exceptions.scala:122)
    at play.api.Application$$anonfun$3.apply(Application.scala:71)
    at play.api.Application$$anonfun$3.apply(Application.scala:67)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:17)
    at play.api.Application.<init>(Application.scala:66)
    at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:49)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:132)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$5.apply(NettyServer.scala:153)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$5.apply(NettyServer.scala:152)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:152)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Global cannot be cast to play.GlobalSettings
    at play.api.Application.liftedTree1$1(Application.scala:44)
    at play.api.Application.play$api$Application$$javaGlobal(Application.scala:43)
    at play.api.Application$$anonfun$3.apply(Application.scala:68)
    ... 10 more
```

Here's my code:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.Play.current
import akka.util.duration._
import play.api.libs.concurrent._

/**
 * @author Sebastien Lorber (<i>lorber.sebastien@gmail.com</i>)
 * Date: 21/11/12 - Time: 21:55
 */
class Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application has started")
    startElasticSearchIndexationScheduling
  }

  override def onStop(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application shutdown...")
  }

  def startElasticSearchIndexationScheduling = {
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(5 seconds, 15 seconds) {
      Logger.info("Doing ElasticSearch reindexation (TODO: just testing scheduler")
    }
  }


}
```

Nothing fancy like you see...

By the way, I don't understand why there is often 2 different packages for objects of the same name`play.GlobalSettings` / `play.api.GlobalSettings` etc. One object seems to be for Java usage and the other for Scala, but the package name make this not very obvious. And I'm using Scala with a Scala global object importing "play.api.GlobalSettings" so why does it need to try to cast to `play.GlobalSettings` which seems more Java oriented (I tried extending this one and it doesn't work either, and it's not what the tutorial says)

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use an object, not a class with the Scala Global object:

```
...
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
...
}
```

Take a look at the Play documentation on [Global object with Scala](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaGlobal)

About the `play.*` against `play.api.*`, it is sure that it is not obvious to make the difference. Let's just say that the Play's core is Scala (api), and the Java part is just a wrapper around it.

Comment: arf thanks for the catch i didn't notice that i wrote class instead of object :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using `play.api.GlobalSettings` for Scala, not `play.GlobalSettings` which is the Java version. Otherwise you can get this class casting warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a class with a companion object:

`class Global extends WithFilters...`

`object Global extends Global`

then it also fails at start time with the same error. The solution is to make the class abstract:

`abstract class Global extends WithFilters...`

This is because Play! first looks for a java Global, which is a class, before looking for a scala Global, which is an object.